# Remove sidebar from product categories which display type is subcategories in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar, custom-taxonomy

I'd like to write a function that removes the sidebar from any product category page in woocommerce whose display type is subcategories.

Some kind of function that says if this category has display type subcategories then disappear the sidebar.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you any solution for flatsome theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mainly depend on your theme own customizations. So the following code will only handle:

- The default woocommerce behavior based on `woocommerce_sidebar` action hook.
- The storefront theme based on storefront_sidebar action hook.

**The custom conditional function:**

First, here below is a custom conditional function that will check if a product category term is set with `'subcategories'` display type:

```
// Custom conditional function that check for "subcategories" display type in product categories term
function is_subcategory_display_type( $term ) {
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

    if( ! term_exists( $term, $taxonomy ) )
        return false;

    if( ! is_numeric( $term ) )
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', sanitize_title( $term ), $taxonomy )->term_id;

    return get_term_meta( $term, 'display_type', true ) === 'subcategories' ?  true : false;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### Then you will add one of those depending on your theme:

**1) For normal themes** using the default `woocommerce_sidebar` hook:

```
// Removing default themes woocommerce sidebar conditionally
add_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'remove_woocommerce_sidebar', 1, 1 );
function remove_woocommerce_sidebar( $name ){

    $queried_object_id = get_queried_object_id();

    if ( is_product_category() && is_subcategory_display_type( $queried_object_id ) ){
        remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar','woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**2) For Storefront theme** using it's own `storefront_sidebar` hook:

```
// Removing default "Storefront" theme woocommerce sidebar conditionally
add_action( 'storefront_sidebar', 'remove_storefront_get_sidebar', 1, 1 );
function remove_storefront_get_sidebar( $name ){

    $queried_object_id = get_queried_object_id();

    if ( is_product_category() && is_subcategory_display_type( $queried_object_id ) ){
        remove_action('storefront_sidebar','storefront_get_sidebar', 10 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**3) Other themes** with specific customizations:

> You will have to find out which hook is used to make the code work.

Comment: Thanks A lot! It does work! There's just one little niggle... the main content still thinks there is a sidebar there so the css is making it smaller. Is there a way, other than bodging it as I would, to get it to go full width?

Comment: I think I figured it out on my own.... with some help from stackoverflow! Here's the mod's I made to your theme function. What do you think? Is there a better way? I added this to the if in your theme function
   `
    ?>
    <style>
        .content-area { width:100%;}
    </style>
    <?php`

Comment: Not sure how to format these comments so sorry it's a bit of a blur... I tried :(

Comment: Have you any solution for flatsome theme?

Answer (score 0):

By default, woocommerce uses the default type (displays subcategories if they exist and products if there are no subcategories)
To check the current value, use a conditional function:

```
woocommerce_products_will_display()
```

So you can remove the sidebar like this:

```
function remove_storefront_sidebar( $name ){
  if ( is_product_category() && !woocommerce_products_will_display() ){
    remove_action('storefront_sidebar','storefront_get_sidebar', 10 );
  }
}
add_action( 'storefront_sidebar', 'remove_storefront_sidebar');
```

---

Another option is to hide only if the display type is "subcategories":

```
function remove_storefront_sidebar( $name ){
  $display_type = woocommerce_get_loop_display_mode();
  if ( is_product_category() && 'subcategories' === $display_type ){
    remove_action('storefront_sidebar','storefront_get_sidebar', 10 );
  }
}
add_action( 'storefront_sidebar', 'remove_storefront_sidebar');
```

Comment: Have you any solution for flatsome theme?